# Why use setters in java instead of constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, getter-setter, setter

Setters serve only a single function of constructors in java i.e assigning value to instance variables. Why do we need them? Can you explain with an example? 
I understand the question I asked was rudimentary and I am sorry for that. I am new to programming and as soon as I found stackoverflow, I asked this question which has been bugging me for quite a time. I tried deleting, but that was not allowed.

Comment: Setters allow you to mutate the state of an object after initialization.  On the other hand, a constructor can only set state once.

Comment: Because obviously you sometimes want to change values in an already existing object. Only allowing setting values in constructor would make every object immutable.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't mean constructors by saying constructors? Is it possible you mean setting values of non-private fields?

Answer (score 2):

Because you can change the value later for the same instance. For example, let's assume a person with the following class:

```
public class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

Imagine there is a woman named **"Linda Croft"** which is now single.

```
Person linda = new Person("Linda", "Croft");
```

Then, after a couple of years, he marry a man named **"John Wick"**. Then "Linda" want to change her name to his husband name after marriage. If we don't have a setter, we need to create another "Linda", which is obviously another person:

```
Person anotherLinda = new Person("Linda", "Wick");
```

with the setter, we can update her name with:

```
linda.setLastName("Wick");
```

Now Linda name is **"Linda Wick"**.